# Tensorflow real time object detection

Tags: tensorflow

I am making a real time object detector as my project . I have the following doubts :
1) how many images of each item should I take to train accurately ?
2) will the model which has earlier been  trained on different objects detect those objects if I used that to train other objects ?
3) which object detector model should I use ?

Comment: Your question is a little broad. Your question may get closed.

Answer (score 3):

1) With tensorflow you can start with 150-200 images of each class to start testing with some decent initial results. You may have to increase the images based on results

2) Yes

3) You could start with any of the models, like ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco
Here are all of the models available which are trained on COCO dataset

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

Each of the pre-trained model is different from others in terms of speed of detection, accuracy etc., Based on your needs you need to pick

Additionally Seems you are new to Obeject detection, refer the following articles if you need a start on how to do

https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-toy-detector-with-tensorflow-object-detection-api-63c0fdf2ac95

https://medium.com/@dana.yu/training-a-custom-object-detection-model-41093ddc5797